# Is it possible to add attributes to armor?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make it so when you wear a full set (or individual pieces) of armor it will give you speed 2. Is this possible to do without things like MC Edit?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to execute a command as any player wearing diamond boots:

```
/execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:100b,id:"minecraft:diamond_boots}]}] run say I wear diamond boots.
```

You can use this to execute a command as any player wearing a full set of diamond armor:

```
/execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:100b,id:"minecraft:diamond_boots"},{Slot:101b,id:"minecraft:diamond_leggings"},{Slot:102b,id:"minecraft:diamond_chestplate"},{Slot:103b,id:"minecraft:diamond_helmet"}]}] run say I wear a full set of diamond armor.
```

You can use this to execute a command as any player wearing a full set of blue leather armor:

```
/execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:100b,id:"minecraft:leather_boots",tag:{display:{color:3949738}}},{Slot:101b,id:"minecraft:leather_leggings",tag:{display:{color:3949738}}},{Slot:102b,id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",tag:{display:{color:3949738}}},{Slot:103b,id:"minecraft:leather_helmet",tag:{display:{color:3949738}}}]}] run say I wear a full set of blue leather armor.
```

Comment: This answers everything. Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, I noticed when I tested it that it wouldn't work. Could it be because of the fact that the armor is enchanted and named?

Comment: @SillyEar7 What version of minecraft do you use?

Comment: 1.14.3 (it wont let me write less than 8 characters or something so i have to write this )

Comment: @SillyEar7 The name and enchantment shouldn't be a problem, what command do you try to use and what armor do you use?

Comment: I used: /execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:100b,id:"minecraft:leather_boots",tag:{display:{color:3949738}}},{Slot:101b,id:"minecraft:leather_leggings",tag:{display:{color:3949738}}},{Slot:102b,id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",tag:{display:{color:3949738}}},{Slot:103b,id:"minecraft:leather_helmet",tag:{display:{color:3949738}}}]}] run say I wear a full set of blue leather armor

Comment: And I used blue leather armor.

Comment: `3949738` is the color code for the blue that you get when you color your leather armor with lapis lazuli, or the dye that you get from lapis lazuli. Is that the dye that you used? Also, you may try to use this command to give yourself blue leather armor (in this case boots): `/give @s leather_boots{tag:{display:{color:3949738}}}`. If this still doesn't help, try to use `/data get entity @s Inventory` to find what data the slots `100`-`103` contain.

Comment: Ok, I will test that today, thank you!